# Compare SQL groups against eachother

Tags: sql, group-by

How can one filter a grouped resultset for only those groups that meet some criterion compared against the other groups?  For example, only those groups that have the maximum number of constituent records?

I had thought that a subquery as follows should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT   *, COUNT(*) AS Records
    FROM     T
    GROUP BY X
) t HAVING Records = MAX(Records);
```

However the addition of the final `HAVING` clause results in an empty recordset... what's going on?

Comment: If Juho's answer doesn't give you what you need, please enter what type of database you are using (oracle, mysql, sql server, etc.) (by using the tags, where you put in sql.  If you want only generic sql solutiones, mention that in the body of your message).  If you have take time to put some sample data and table structures up in your post and at sqlfiddle.com, you'll make it easier for people to look at your question in more depth.

Comment: @LevinMagruder: MySQL 5.1; sample data at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4306/4

Comment: okay, I don't use mysql, but someone will show you a simpler query than the one I showed below, mark their answer as the answer, but if my answer's helpful and you want to shoot me an upvote, thanks.  If you have a lot of problems like this maybe also read questions tagged "greatest-n-per-group," there's lot's of interesting approaches.

Comment: @LevinMagruder: Thanks Levin; I will upvote your answer as it is indeed helpful (and one strategy for dealing with the problem), but I'll hold out for an answer that saves repeating the subquery (if at all possible!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the exact question you give, one way to look at it is that you want the group of records where there is no other group that has more records. So if you say

```
SELECT taxid, COUNT(*) as howMany
GROUP by taxid
```

You get all counties and their counts

Then you can treat that expressions as a table by making it a subquery, and give it an alias.  Below I assign two "copies" of the query the names X and Y and ask for taxids that don't have any more in one table.  If there are two with the same number I'd get two or more.  Different databases have proprietary syntax, notably TOP and LIMIT, that make this kind of query simpler, easier to understand.

```
SELECT taxid FROM
(select taxid, count(*) as HowMany from flats
GROUP by taxid) as X

WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT * from 
(
   SELECT taxid, count(*) as HowMany FROM
   flats 
   GROUP by taxid
   ) AS Y
  WHERE Y.howmany > X.howmany
)
```

Comment: I'm aware that by repeating the subquery in the `WHERE` clause I am able to extract the maximum number of rows (just using `max()` there works fine), but it seems rather wasteful to invoke the same subquery multiple times; is there any way to reference the temporary table resulting from the subquery in the `FROM` clause within the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL (Which I assume you are using since you have posted `SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM T GROUP BY X` Which would fail in all RDBMS that I know of). You can use:

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  X, COUNT(*) AS Records
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY X
            ORDER BY Records DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) T2
            ON T2.X = T.X
```

This has been tested in MySQL and removes the implicit grouping/aggregation.

If you can use windowed functions and one of TOP/LIMIT with Ties or Common Table expressions it becomes even shorter:

**Windowed function + CTE:**  (MS SQL-Server & PostgreSQL Tested)

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY X) AS Records
    FROM    T
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
WHERE   Records = (SELECT MAX(Records) FROM CTE)
```

**Windowed Function with TOP** (MS SQL-Server Tested)

```
SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM    (   SELECT  *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY X) [Records]
            FROM    T
        )
ORDER BY Records DESC
```

Lastly, I have never used oracle so apolgies for not adding a solution that works on oracle...

---

**EDIT**

My Solution for MySQL did not take into account ties, and my suggestion for a solution to this kind of steps on the toes of what you have said you want to avoid (duplicate subqueries) so I am not sure I can help after all, however just in case it is preferable here is a version that will work as required on your fiddle:

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  X
            FROM    T
            GROUP BY X
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 
                    (   SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Records
                        FROM    T
                        GROUP BY X
                        ORDER BY Records DESC
                        LIMIT 1
                    )
        ) T2
            ON T2.X = T.X
```

Comment: The first (mysql) one does lose ties though; which might be what eggyal wants, if not I think you have to recast it to match on count.  The last two don't lose ties.

Comment: @LevinMagruder Yeah, noticed this a couple of minutes ago, have added an edit but now I also don't think it is what the OP wants as it repeats the subquery, but as far as I can work out this is inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, MAX(Records) as max_records FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Records
    FROM T
    GROUP BY X
  ) t
) WHERE Records = max_records
```

I'm sorry that I can't test the validity of this query right now.

Comment: The `SELECT MAX(Records)` in your second-level query truncates the recordset to only one record in which the `Records` and `max_records` fields are not necessarily the same (and therefore the overall result will only ever consist of zero or one record); perhaps this is what was implied by my original query and hence no results?